# Problems installing PECL extension Memcache

Tags: centos, php, memcached

I have installed memcached fine and seems working properly , and now I will need to install PECL extension memcache. Im running Centos 6.2 x86_64 .When I try to install  gives me this error at the bottom :

```
downloading memcached-2.2.0.tgz ...
Starting to download memcached-2.2.0.tgz (70,449 bytes)
.................done: 70,449 bytes
15 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
libmemcached directory [no] : no
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootpyG6h1/memcached-2.2.0
running: /var/tmp/memcached/configure --with-libmemcached-dir=no
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/i                                 nclude/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/ph                                 p/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable memcached support... yes, shared
checking for libmemcached... yes, shared
checking whether to enable memcached session handler support... yes
checking whether to enable memcached igbinary serializer support... no
checking whether to enable memcached json serializer support... no
checking whether to enable memcached msgpack serializer support... no
checking whether to enable memcached sasl support... yes
checking whether to enable memcached protocol support... no
checking for ZLIB... yes, shared
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for zlib location... /usr
checking for session includes... /usr/include/php
checking for memcached session support... enabled
checking for memcached igbinary support... disabled
checking for memcached msgpack support... disabled
checking for libmemcached location... found version 0.31, under /usr
checking whether to enable sasl support... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sasl/sasl.h usability... yes
checking sasl/sasl.h presence... yes
checking for sasl/sasl.h... yes
checking whether libmemcached supports sasl... no
configure: error: no, libmemcached sasl support is not enabled. Run configure wi                                 th --disable-memcached-sasl to disable this check
ERROR: `/var/tmp/memcached/configure --with-libmemcached-dir=no' failed
```

Memcached Stat is :

```
memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 stats
#127.0.0.1:11211   Field       Value
         accepting_conns           1
               auth_cmds           0
             auth_errors           0
                   bytes           0
              bytes_read          81
           bytes_written        1149
              cas_badval           0
                cas_hits           0
              cas_misses           0
               cmd_flush           0
                 cmd_get           0
                 cmd_set           0
               cmd_touch           0
             conn_yields           0
   connection_structures          11
       crawler_reclaimed           0
        curr_connections          10
              curr_items           0
               decr_hits           0
             decr_misses           0
             delete_hits           0
           delete_misses           0
       evicted_unfetched           0
               evictions           0
       expired_unfetched           0
                get_hits           0
              get_misses           0
              hash_bytes      524288
       hash_is_expanding           0
        hash_power_level          16
               incr_hits           0
             incr_misses           0
                libevent 2.0.22-stable
          limit_maxbytes    67108864
     listen_disabled_num           0
       lrutail_reflocked           0
            malloc_fails           0
                     pid       28884
            pointer_size          64
               reclaimed           0
            reserved_fds          20
           rusage_system    0.000999
             rusage_user    0.000999
                 threads           4
                    time  1431481315
       total_connections          14
             total_items           0
              touch_hits           0
            touch_misses           0
                  uptime       59682
                 version      1.4.22
```

and

```
netstat -tap | grep memcached
tcp        0      0 *:memcache                  *:*                         LISTEN      28884/memcached
tcp        0      0 *:memcache                  *:*                         LISTEN      28884/memcached
```

Ps aux

```
 ps aux | grep memcached
    root      8998  0.0  0.0 103236   856 pts/1    S+   11:45   0:00 grep memcached
    492      28884  0.0  0.0 338100  1320 ?        Ssl  May12   0:00 memcached -d -p 11211 -u memcached -m 64 -c 1024 -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
```

Pecl List

```
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package  Version State
APC      3.1.13  beta
memcache 3.0.8   beta
```

I would really appreciate some advice to solve this problem THX

`yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` and `yum install zlib-devel` has been already installed

I tried to run `yum install memcached-beta --disable-memcached-sasl` and `yum install memcached-beta --enable-memcached-sasl=no`
but with the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcached >2.1 requires at least libmemcached 1.x. 
You seem to have 0.31 still installed.

Remove the current libmemcached packages and install libmemcached10 (plus the -devel).

These packages can be found in (at least) IUS repository.

Comment: Thank you Mick I followed  your advice and seems to be install and working , however doesn't seems to appear to the php info  , also installing prestashop also is not recognized 
phpInfo:
'http://tinyurl.com/lgerjsh'
any advice ?

Comment: Thank you so much I solve the problem with your solution  and for the rest I update Prestashop and everything is Fine